# Flash AS3 ... Visible = false not working?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

So I have a simple flash movie.

I have created 3 layers (actions, background, header) Background contains an image, header contains a movie clip with an instance name of "mc_header". In the actions layer I have said mc_header.visible = false; Yet when testing the movie it continues to show for no reason.

Comment: Can you post some code or give steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What happens if you trace(mc_header) right before mc_header.visible?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure when you say "instance" are you referring to the name of the layer or the actual name of the movie clip? From the question and description this seems like it might be a valid point.

Another problem could be if you are doing a timeline animation and using keyframes. If the movie clip is not present (on the timeline and stage) when you call the actionscript then the action is not performed.

It might be faster if you just provide the source files so we could help you faster.

Cheers!

Comment: It sounds like might be using the library name instead of the instance name. That was confusing for me when I started with Flash.

Answer (score 2):

I have corrected this mistake.

This problem appears if clip not wiped in this frame.

I have done animation with 50 frames, the first and the last frame were key. So when I have added the new clip in the first frame that it did not come up for the last frame - he was only in the first frame !!!
To correct the mistake I have deleted the last key frame and created it once again. Hereon clip came up for all frames. It became available on length whole animation.

Answer (score 0):

The way you say this it should work.
Post a link to the source file...